# Why are strings marshalled differently?

Tags: go, yaml

I have the following input file.

```yaml
title: "2023-08-23"
title2: "A title with a colon: inside"
title3: '2023-08-23'
```

Using the following code I get a slightly unexpected result. I use `gopkg.in/yaml.v3` and `go1.20.2 darwin/arm64` for this.

```golang
rawYaml, _ := os.ReadFile("./input.yaml")
yamlMap := make(map[string]string)
yaml.Unmarshal(rawYaml, &yamlMap)

marschalled, _ := yaml.Marshal(yamlMap)
fmt.Println(string(marschalled))
```

The output is the following.

```yaml
title: "2023-08-23"
title2: 'A title with a colon: inside'
title3: "2023-08-23"
```

My questions is, why is `title` still encapsulated in double quotes but `title2` is only encapsulated with single quotes and `title3` even gets switched over.

Comment: You can take a look at the logic [on GitHub](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/blob/f6f7691b1fdeb513f56608cd2c32c51f8194bf51/encode.go#L324-L363). It doesn't seem to explain this behavior though; would it be possible that the title contains a linefeed, or is this the exact input file you're testing with? (also, what is the issue with it switching the quotations as long as it emits proper YAML? the contract seems to be upheld)

Comment: @Luatic It's the exact input, so no linefeed or similar. Just extended my question with `title3` which makes it even more confusing.

Comment: `title3` is as expected. The information which quotes were used is completely lost when reading it as a map of strings. Thus it's no surprise that it gets formatted the same way as the first `2023-08-23` - these are simply the same strings.

Comment: Agree on `title3`. Nevertheless the behavior overall is pretty inconsistent because all three should be simple strings after reading them.

Comment: YAML is a beast.

Comment: All three *are* simple strings after reading them; [the input YAML has nothing to do with it](https://go.dev/play/p/hcZ58vdfHD1). String quoting is based on content (possibly [this part of libyaml](https://github.com/yaml/libyaml/blob/f8f760f7387d2cc56a2fc7b1be313a3bf3f7f58c/src/emitter.c#L1591) for this particular string), and you can also end up with no quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luatic has pointed out, the first step in the logic is to decide whether we can use a plain scalar based on whether the string, if written as a plain scalar, would load into a string again. The relevant code is in [this function](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/blob/f6f7691b1fdeb513f56608cd2c32c51f8194bf51/encode.go#L324-L363):

```golang
        // Check to see if it would resolve to a specific
        // tag when encoded unquoted. If it doesn't,
        // there's no need to quote it.
        rtag, _ := resolve("", s)
        canUsePlain = rtag == strTag && !(isBase60Float(s) || isOldBool(s))
```

So we try to resolve the tag of `s` (which means: we ask the resolver what type it thinks a plain scalar with this content would have) and if it's a string, we know it's safe to write the string as unquoted scalar. We also check for base60 floats and „old bools“ (`yes`, `no` etc) from YAML 1.1 because we want to avoid those as lots of implementations still accept them.

This is the *semantic* side of things. Since both `2023-08-23` reads as a date, the code determines it must put it in double quotes. This is why you'll get double quotes for these two values. It has absolutely nothing to do with how they looked originally.

But what about the single quotes? Well, this is not the last check we do before emitting. The emitter must also ensure that it is *syntactially* allowed to emit the string in plain style. [This function](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/blob/f6f7691b1fdeb513f56608cd2c32c51f8194bf51/emitterc.go#L1255-L1406) is what does that, specifically these lines:

```golang
    if flow_indicators {
        emitter.scalar_data.flow_plain_allowed = false
    }
    if block_indicators {
        emitter.scalar_data.block_plain_allowed = false
    }
```

A colon is a flow indicator and, if followed by whitespace, also a block indicator. So the emitter decides that it cannot emit this scalar in plain style, because it contains a colon. When [selecting a scalar style](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml/blob/f6f7691b1fdeb513f56608cd2c32c51f8194bf51/emitterc.go#L1004-L1050), it thus selects the single-quoted style, which is reasonable.

Now if you want to keep the style if the input, you have to deserialize it in a form that preserves the information about the original style. This is done via `yaml.Node`:

```golang
    var node yaml.Node
    yaml.Unmarshal(rawYaml, &node)

    marschalled, err := yaml.Marshal(&node)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(marschalled))
```

[Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/rolGbRctYyc). Output:

```yaml
title: "2023-08-23"
title2: "A title with a colon: inside"
title3: '2023-08-23'
```